# duplicate action on stream redux observable

Tags: socket.io, redux-observable

I got duplicate action firing when I subscribe to a socket io event.

`const onStartGameActionEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(ON_START_GAME),
    mergeMap(() =>
      fromEvent(socket, 'newGameCreated').pipe(
        map(response => onStartGameFulfilled(response)),
      ),
    ),
  );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new listener every time `ON_START_GAME`occurs, but you're never killing off the old ones. That's the root of the issue.

## Fix 1

Change `mergeMap` to `switchMap`.

## Fix 2

You might want to have multiple games going at once. If so, assign a `namespace` prop to your `ON_START_GAME` action. When the game end action fires, kill off that specific observable.

```js
const onStartGameActionEpic = (action$, state$) =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType(ON_START_GAME),
        mergeMap(onStartGameAction =>
            fromEvent(socket, 'newGameCreated').pipe(
                takeUntil(action$.pipe(
                    ofType(ON_END_GAME),
                    filter(onEndGameAction => (
                        endGameAction.namespace === startGameAction.namespace
                    )),
                )),
                map(response => onStartGameFulfilled(response)),
            ),
        ),
    );
```